# How do I detect whether I am on server on client in next.js?

Tags: express, next.js

I am using a customer express server with Next.js. It's running within a container. I am doing an http request with `isomorphic-fetch` to get data for my render. I'd like to do `localhost` when running on server and `mysite.com` when running on client. Not sure the best way to accomplish this. I can do it hackily by doing `const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'` but that seems pretty bad.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Now (2020 Jan) it should be `typeof window === 'undefined'` since `process.browser` is deprecated

Refer to https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5354#issuecomment-520305040

Comment: Great answer! Adding a note, though, that if you're using Typescript and, like me, you get the error "cannot find name window", it is because you need to add `"dom"` to your `lib` array in tsconfig.json. For some reason Next.js doesn't include this by default.

Comment: Client side also has worker thread scopes, where `window` is not defined.
A keyword that is available in both the main browser thread and workers would be `self`, so the check could be `typeof self === 'undefined'`.
On top of that, you can define a global named `window` or `self` on the server, which would invalidate this method.

Comment: Probably `globalThis.window` is the most flexible way on every environment? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

Answer (score 76):

You can use `process.browser` to distinguish between server environment (NodeJS) and client environment (browser).

`process.browser` is `true` on the client and `undefined` on the server.

Comment: Also `isServer` is a thing, depending on the Next function call. I did need to use `process.browser` from where I needed the logic though :)

Comment: I think `process.browser` is added by webpack which then propagates to next.js

Comment: Please look at @kenberkeley's answer below instead of using this. `process.browser` is deprecated and using `typeof window` instead will get you in-framework optimizations.

Answer (score 11):

Since I don't like depending on odd third party things for this behavior (even though `process.browser` seems to come from *Webpack*), I think the preferred way to check is for presence of `appContext.ctx.req` like this:

```
async getInitialProps (appContext) {

    if (appContext.ctx.req) // server? 
    {
        //server stuff
    }
    else {
        // client stuff
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2946

Comment: This assumes you are in `getInitialProps` or have access to `appContext`

Comment: I wouldn't use an obscure syntax for a basic concept - an `isClient(appContext)` helper would read much better.

Answer (score 5):

One additional note is that `componentDidMount()` is always called on the browser. I often load the initial data set (seo content in `getInitialProps()`, then load more in depth data in the  `componentDidMount()` method.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the useEffect() hook?

Comment: @jonhobbs Yes, `useEffect` directly replaces `componentDidMount` (plus `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount` all in one). If you just write `useEffect(() => { .. }, [])` then it's the exact equivalent. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 5):

Also, as variant, you can add variable to your `.env` file without `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix.

> Like as:
> `IS_SERVER_FLAG=true`

This variable will be available only on server side

And after, you can check it in your code

`const isServer = process.env.IS_SERVER_FLAG ? 'RUN ON SERVER' : 'RUN_ON_CLIENT'`

Answer (score -3):

[`getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#next-gen-static-site-generation-ssg-support) are added in Next 9.3(Mar 2020), and these functions are [recommended](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps).

> If you're using Next.js 9.3 or newer, we recommend that you use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` instead of `getInitialProps`.

So no need to detect, just put server side stuff in `getServerSideProps`.

```js
const MyPage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // client side stuff
  }, [])

  return (
    <div> ... </div>
  )
}

MyPage.getServerSideProps = async () => {
  // server side stuff
}
```