# In SvelteKit, how do you conditionally include a `<script>` block in `app.html`?

Tags: sveltekit

We have a couple analytics `<script>` blocks that we want on every page, and `app.html` seems like the right place to put this. But it's not a `.svelte` file. How do we conditionally add those script blocks based on a variable?

One alternative considered is putting that conditional code block in `__layout.svelte`, although that doesn't seem right given how different pages might use `__layout.reset.svelte`, and then miss getting the analytics code included.

How is this accomplished in SvelteKit?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need a `<script>` tag or just to load the associated JavaScript code?

In both cases, you can do this on the Svelte component/SvelteKit route `onMount` by

1 ) Checking you are running in a web browser - you probably don't want to fire any events on server-side rendering

2 a) Loading ES6 modules dynamically

or

2 b) Use `document` API to manipulate the DOM tree and insert `<script>` tag to the `<head>`

For 2.a) here are some examples I have done:

```js
     // Dynamically loaded uPlot library
     let uPlot = null;

    /**
     * We can only import uPlot on the client side.
     */
    onMount(async () => {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57030895/whats-the-best-way-to-run-some-code-only-client-side
        if (browser) {
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports
            const uplotModule = await import('uplot');
            // console.log("uPlot imported dynamically", uplotModule, uplotModule.default);
            // This will trigger candle redraw if candles data was raced faster than uplot
            uPlot = uplotModule.default;
        }
    });
```

You can [read the full source code here](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/blob/master/src/routes/trading-view/%5Bchain%5D/%5Bexchange%5D/%5Bpair%5D/index.svelte). [You can inspect a live example e.g. here](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/binance/pancakeswap-v2/pwr-busd)

For 2.b) you can [do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121948/dynamically-add-script-tag-with-src-that-may-include-document-write).

However the best way to solve the situation would not load anything dynamically, but extract the analytics code and run the code as it in `__layout` or `onMount`, or rewrite it to be Svelte compatible.

Comment: Yeah, one is google's tag manger, i.e. `<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>`. It's a client-only static site (no SSR), so I think runtime insertion of <script> blocks is my only real choice. Your examples are helpful.  If SvelteKit offered an `app.svelte` file rather than `app.html` it might be a little easier to implement.

Comment: You need to manually fire gtag events in component `onMount`. The stock gtag script will not help you.