# Using uPlot with svelte, does not render

Tags: javascript, svelte, uplot

I'm struggling to make [uPlot](https://github.com/leeoniya/uPlot) work with [svelte](https://svelte.dev/). I can't find any minimal working example, so I'm crafting one myself and it does not render. Repro goes as follows:

```bash
npm create svelte repro

# y
# skeleton
# yes TypeScript
# yes ESLing
# yes Prettier
# yes Playwright

npm install
npm i uplot
npm run dev -- --open
```

And then I modify `index.svelte` to contain the following (best I could come up with, thanks to this answer [In SvelteKit, how do you conditionally include a `<script>` block in `app.html`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701554/in-sveltekit-how-do-you-conditionally-include-a-script-block-in-app-html/70701665#70701665))

```
<script lang="ts">

    import { browser } from '$app/env';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import "uplot/dist/uPlot.min.css"

    let uPlot;

    function redraw(uPlot) {

        if(!uPlot) return;

        let data = [new Float32Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), new Float32Array([1, 3, 2, 5, 4])];

        const opts = {
            width: 600,
            height: 300,
            scales: {x: {time: false}},
            series: [{label: "x"}, {label: "y", stroke: "red"}],
        };

        new uPlot(opts, data, document.getElementById("uPlot"));
    }

    onMount(async () => {

        if (browser) {
            const uplotModule = await import('uplot');
            uPlot = uplotModule.default;
            console.log("uplot loaded", uplotModule, uPlot);
        }
    })

    $: redraw(uPlot)

</script>

<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
<div id="uPlot"></div>
```

It does not render the plot :( What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure your `async` `onMount`  implementation is correct? Can you try something like [this](https://svelte.dev/repl/7e175db016b74c4ba4688c76114866c9?version=3.23.0) and see if it works?

Comment: I'm not sure of anything :( With my implementation I get no errors, and an empty plot element appears that reacts to mouse movements, but shows no plot. I tried to fit things to your example, but I got lost. I'm not sure what is supposed to go to onMount and to lazyLoading :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to fix or improve:

- uPlot does *not* take typed arrays as data
- The reactive statement is a bit pointless, as it only triggers in a meaningful once after uPlot has been loaded
- One should not query the DOM in Svelte but use `bind:this` or events instead
- `onMount` already executes only in the browser

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import 'uplot/dist/uPlot.min.css';

    let plotContainer;

    function redraw(uPlot) {
        let data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]];

        const opts = {
            width: 600,
            height: 300,
            scales: {x: {time: false}},
            series: [{label: "x"}, {label: "y", stroke: "red"}],
        };

        new uPlot(opts, data, plotContainer);
    }

    onMount(async () => {
        const uplotModule = await import('uplot');
        const uPlot = uplotModule.default;
        redraw(uPlot);
    })
</script>

<div bind:this={plotContainer}></div>
```

[REPL equivalent](https://svelte.dev/repl/ae0bf9a7e5574e0d83dcf6c86cf16d80?version=3.48.0)