# How to use portals in Next.js in getting the child element outside the immediate parent container?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-tsx

#### Current Implementation

Container

```
export const FormContainer = () => {
    return (<Form/>);
  }
```

Component

```
export const Form = () => {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <aside>
        <div>{"I am a component"}<div/>
      </aside>,
      document.body
    );
  }
```

#### Errors

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

#### Expectation

I want the Form to be out of FormContainer DOM hierarchy.

Comment: hi, are you getting this error in next js terminal (your ide terminal) or inside the browser console?

Comment: @Pierfrancesco  getting this error on browser

Answer (score 2):

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

`ReactDOM.createPortal` is more like a "BrowserSide only" component because it needs `document` and in serverSide Rendering, it's undefined.

> I want the Form to be out of FormContainer DOM hierarchy.

easiest solution:
set a condition to check for BrowserOnly rendering of `createPortal` component :

according to [saimeunt answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49412514/14060791), something like

```
export const FormContainer = () => {
    return (
        {process.browser?
            <Form/>:null
        }
    );
}
```

will make the day.

another way around will be using nextJs [dynamic import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) and disable SSR on module

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Form = dynamic(() => import("path/to/FormModule"), { ssr: false });


export const FormContainer = () => {
    return (<Form/>);
  }
```