# Why is Next.js _app.js called by both client and server?

Tags: next.js

I'm using a custom `_app.tsx` component in my `Next.js` app like so:

```
const MyApp = ({Component, pageProps}) => {

  let ClientSideAuthProvider = (({children}) => <>{children}</>) // SERVER-SIDE BY DEFAULT

  if (process.browser) { // CLIENT-SIDE
    const {AuthProvider} = require('utils/auth')
    ClientSideAuthProvider = AuthProvider
  }
  
  console.log('CLIENT_SIDE ' + process.browser)

  return (
    <ClientSideAuthProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ClientSideAuthProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

The strange and somewhat unexpected thing is that the `console.log` statement appears on both the browser console (`CLIENT_SIDE true`) and Node.js console (`CLIENT_SIDE false`). Which is why I'm having to make the check in my code so that my `AuthProvider`, which uses a client-side library, isn't called on the server, which causes issues that break my app.

For now this works, but it feels like a workaround that shouldn't be there.

It's also probably worth noting that I tested this on a route/page that exports `getServerSideProps`.

So, is it by design that `_app.tsx` would be called both on the client as well as on the server side?

Comment: Also, [`process.browser` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59562136/11613622).

Comment: @Danila, kind of. Does it apply to `_app` the same way, meaning its code is executed twice because the page is rendered twice?

Comment: Yes, the page is rendered on the server at first and send to the browser as html, then it gets hydrated on the client